# Multiple commands produce '/Users/...Debug-iphonesimulator/cocoapods-artifacts-Debug.txt':

Tags: xcode, github, cocoa

Version control woes.

When I pulled my project onto another machine it refused to compile - giving error

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/.../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/cocoapods-artifacts-Debug.txt':
1) That command depends on command in Target '____' (project '____'): script phase “[CP] Prepare Artifacts”
2) That command depends on command in Target '___UITests' (project '_____'): script phase “[CP] Prepare Artifacts”
```

And it was deeply annoying and frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

So the fix was as follows:

I had used pod update when I should have used pod install (or possibly vice versa. I am trying to be a good citizen recording notes - but I don't want to break my project again to recreate the steps!).

I also reinstalled cocoapods on my backup machine this may or may not have been part of the fix.